# Controlling activity instance visibility through a service?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

I have an activity which can be launched from two sources. Each source launches it's own instance of the activity:
1. From inside an application
2. From an external service

My problem is with the service. The service needs to be able to control the visibility of the activity on the Android screen (hide and show the activity).

Currently I start the activity from the service with the following intent:

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent("Custom_Action");
appIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

startActivity(appIntent);
```

My question is, how can I control the visibility of the activity. Maybe through binding the activity to the service?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how services and activities relate. A service runs in the background, doing it's thing.  It has no UI and no way for the user to interact with it.  The activity can send the service messages and query its state but the service has no way to push information to an activity.  If you want the service to notify the user of something you can post a notification.  Then have that notification launch your activity which will then connect to the service.  There is no way to force open an activity from a service because there is no way to know if your user is even looking at their device at that time.

Comment: I know that it is possible to bind to a service, and give it a callback from the activity. So maybe i can some how control the visibility through a callback?